# ReactJS - Mount custom react component into DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a library that any frontend app can include and on calling the boot method I want to attach my custom button into the UI (kinda like the Intercom button [www.intercom.com](https://intercom.com)).

I define a namespace that I add to the window like so:

```
import MyButton from "./MyButton"

declare global {
    interface Window {
        MyClient: {
            boot: () => void;
        };
    }
}

export namespace MyClient {
    export const boot = () => {
        const container = document.getElementById('app');
        if (container) {
           // TODO: how can I mount MyButton?
        }
    };
}

window.MyClient = MyClient || {};
```

I am using vite+rollupJS to bundle my code into a library that eventually gets included like so in the client's frontend app:

```
<script src="/dist/my-client-lib.js"></script>
```

and later in his scripts

```
window.MyClient.boot();
```

Comment: mount it into an element like you would any react component? using https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot  + `root.render(..)` as per example there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import MyButton from "./MyButton"
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

declare global {
    interface Window {
        MyClient: {
            boot: () => void;
        };
    }
}

export namespace MyClient {
    export const boot = () => {
        const container = document.getElementById('app');
        if (container) {
           const root = createRoot(container);
           root.render(<MyButton />)
        }
    };
}

window.MyClient = MyClient || {};
```